# Aggregation Exception: The key 'cursor' could not be found in this document or array

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have a Play Framework Scala application hitting MongoDB using ReactiveMongo. The versions are as follows:

```
Scala 2.12
Play 2.6.17
MongoDB 3.6.9 (on Heroku)
ReactiveMongo (via play2-reactivemongo): 0.15.0-play26
```

I am using the Aggregation Framework support in RM likes so:

```
collection.aggregate(
      Match(BSONDocument("categoryId" -> BSONDocument("$in" -> categories.map(_.id)))), 
      List(Sort(Ascending("position")),  Group(BSONString("$categoryId"))("cars" -> PushField("$ROOT")))
)
```

The code works on MongoDB 3.4.6, but the problem is that on 3.6.9 this code produces the following exception:

```
reactivemongo.bson.exceptions.DocumentKeyNotFound: The key 'cursor' could not be found in this document or array
at reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument.$anonfun$getTry$2(types.scala:1019)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument.getTry(types.scala:1019)
at reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument.getAsTry(types.scala:1061)
at reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.BSONAggregationImplicits$AggregationResultReader$.readResult(aggregation.scala:98)
at reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.BSONAggregationImplicits$AggregationResultReader$.readResult(aggregation.scala:89)
at reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.DealingWithGenericCommandErrorsReader.read(bsoncommands.scala:52)
at reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.DealingWithGenericCommandErrorsReader.read$(bsoncommands.scala:41)
at reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.BSONAggregationImplicits$AggregationResultReader$.read(aggregation.scala:89)
at reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.BSONAggregationImplicits$AggregationResultReader$.read(aggregation.scala:89)
```

The error message and stack trace offer nothing helpful, so has anyone encountered and solved the same error?

Comment: Which data are you use? What is `'cursor'`? https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo-BSON/search?q=cursor&unscoped_q=cursor

Comment: reactivemongo 0.15.0 is really old, I would try to update to the latest version, e.g. 0.19.7. There are lots of bugs fixed and improvements made.

Comment: Certainly upgrading is always an option, but that is never trivial--especially with RM, which while powerful, is notorious for introducing significant breaking changes with each version. Also, the same code works in production on Mongo 3.6.12 (and on Mongo 3.4.6 as mentioned). I'd really like to understand what's going on first before taking any bold action and hoping it helps.

Comment: Maybe it is a server bug. Try to reproduce it locally, then upgrade your server gradually. The error you are seeing is because RM expects a `cursor` element in the answer from the server, but there is none. For example, in 3.6.10 there was a bug fixed regarding aggregations with $match when querying against mongos instances.

Comment: No other way than update the driver to get the fixes.